# Multiplying a one column by another but only if they're highlighted

Tags: vba, excel-formula

First week using VBA but I am trying to multiply one column (X) by another column (AB) and the answer is in another column (AO). But I only want to multiply them if the row they're in is highlighted. I was trying something like this but it only gives me #Name? in column AO and it fills in the area that isn't highlighted.

Rx is the Range for Column X

```
For Each Cell In Rx
    If Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 231, 64) Then
    Range("AO15:AO45") = Evaluate("X15:X45" & "AB15:AB45")
```

Hopefully someone can help me:)

Comment: `range("AO" & Cell.Row) = Range("X" & Cell.Row).Value * Range("AB" & Cell.Row).Value`

Comment: Thank you so Much that is perfect!